Drop table support by JHister using Liquibase
Does JHipster support Drop table scenario?
Use case is i created a JDL with say 4 entities
Generated code and ran the service. It creates tables in the DB
Now In JDL i remove an entity
Perform agao generation
I did not see any entries added for dropping table
Searched in multiple sites but did not get any info
